# Copying templated from different workbook into specific cell on multiple sheets, based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, templates

I am struggling with writing a code to copy paste a template from a separate workbook into a specific cell. The template copied varies depending on the text criteria, which is located in cell A4 on each sheet that the template is supposed to be copied to.

1. go through each sheet on Summary Workbook.
2. On each sheet, in cell A4 there is a specific text that refers to a template
3. Open the template workbook that has multiple template sheets. Copy the template that corresponds to the text in cell A4 of summary workbook sheets
4. go back to the sheet on the summary workbook and paste the template to cell F14 Onwards. (So here do I have to specify the entire cell range of where it needs to be pasted, or would it be fine to just refer to the cell where it should clicked on before pasting)
5. repeat for all the sheets in the Summary workbook

Below is the attempt I made, and I am getting the error "Application defined or objected defined error" I have highlighted the line that triggers the error in the code below. I assume it is because I am not calling the template book sheet correctly. Also I don't if I have to specify the exact range of cells being copied and pasted, because normally if you copy an entire sheet, then you can only paste it as entire sheets as well and not to from a specific cell point.

Thank you for any help!

```
  Sub PASTE()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Summary")
Set Rng = Sht.Range("A6:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\VBA-NOOB\Desktop\EVERY Colour.xlsx")
DoEvents

For Each cell In Rng
   Set ws = wb1.Sheets(cell.Text)
   Select Case ws.Range("A4").Value   
            Case "Red & Green T"
            ws.Range("F14").Value = TemplateBook.Sheets("Red & Green")  '<--- is causing the error

   End Select
   Next cell



   End Sub
```

Comment: Please dont use [tag:macros] tag for VBA! Thx @Peh for the edit! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the the range you want to copy from the template as shown below:

```
   Select Case ws.Range("A4").Value
            Case "Red & Green T"
            TemplateBook.Sheets("Red & Green").Range("F14:Z100").Copy
            ws.Activate
            Range("F14").Select
            ActiveSheet.PASTE
   End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     ws.Range("F14").Value = TemplateBook.Sheets("Red & Green")  '<--- is causing the error
```

In this line you're using two different types of objects. You're trying to say that the value of cell `F14` is the entire worksheet `Red & Green` - not just the cells of `Red & Green`, but the worksheet object. This is why you're getting the error.

I'm a little unclear about exactly what you're trying to do, though - is the idea to take all the contents of the template sheet and paste them into the target worksheet starting at a base cell (F14)? If so, you can do something like this:

```
ws.range("F14").value = TemplateBook.sheets("Red & Green").Range("A1").value
```

...or similar, specifying the size of the source range, rather than trying to use "all cells".

Comment: Yes I want F14 as the base cell to paste into. However there is different template for the different criteria. so in the case if cell A4 in the sheet says Red & Green, then it should copy past from the templatebook red & green sheet. In the code you wrote it doesn't specific which template sheet to use, and I'm not sure how to

Comment: Blech, sorry - I was trying to code and chat at the same time! I've corrected that to include the reference to the TemplateBook.  The key part is using the same type of object on both sides of the `=`. If you're assigning values to a specific cell or range of cells, you need to give it a cell reference, string, integer, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing. Can you try like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub PASTE()

    Dim wb1             As Workbook
    Dim Sht             As Worksheet
    Dim Rng             As Range
    Dim Rng2            As Range
    Dim cell            As Range
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim TemplateBook    As Workbook

    Dim rng3            As Range

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("A6:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\VBA-NOOB\Desktop\EVERY Colour.xlsx")
    DoEvents

    For Each cell In Rng
        Set ws = wb1.Sheets(cell.Text)
        Select Case ws.Range("A4").Value
        Case "Red & Green T"

            ws.Range("F14") = TemplateBook.Sheets("Red & Green").Range("F14")  '<--- is causing the error

        End Select
    Next cell

End Sub
```

What I have changed is here:

```
ws.Range("F14") = TemplateBook.Sheets("Red & Green").Range("F14")
```

In your case you were assigning a Sheet to a range. That is not possible.

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened, the template file opened but there was no error or no copy pasting either. I modified it to specify the range to copy:   ws.Range("F14") = TemplateBook.Sheets("Red & Green").Range("E1:H623")    So I don't know if this why it didn't copy paste anything